# Using jQuery how to change same IDs in the page to serialized IDs for bootstrap Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This how my HTML is rendered in page:

```
<!-- Group-01: Tab One and Two -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab-01" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-02" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-01">Home tab content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-02">About tab content</div>
</div>

<!-- Group-02: Tab One and Two -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab-01" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-02" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-01">Home tab content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-02">About tab content</div>
</div>
```

But this how my HTML I expect to be changed by jQuery:

```
<!-- Group-01: Tab One and Two -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#group-01_tab-01" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group-01_tab-02" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="group-01_tab-01">Home tab content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="group-01_tab-02">About tab content</div>
</div>

<!-- Group-02: Tab One and Two -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#group-02_tab-01" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group-02_tab-02" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="group-02_tab-01">Home tab content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="group-02_tab-02">About tab content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: every ID attributes in a document should be unique... I think the jQuery did properly.

Comment: Syed, the correct way is by having unique ids in the page. So the second solution is correct. The normal way of changing the ids is by changing the `html` directly. Don't you have access to it? Is it generated by some tool you are using?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I am a frontend developer, before passing it to backend developer, I am tying to do maximum work to minimize backend developer's job, so finding solution to fix things in client side first, if not possible, I will let backend developer know to add it through PHP+JS.

Comment: Having backend produce invalid markup and making it valid on the fly in frontend via `JavaScript` can hardly pass as a good development process, IMHO. You should never have duplicate ids in any page, This is common sense, backend or frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var $tabLists = $('[role="tablist"]');
var $contents= $('.tab-content');

$tabLists.each(function(tabListIndex, tabList){
  var groupIndex = tabListIndex + 1;
  var $tabs= $(tabList).find('[data-toggle="tab"]');

  $tabs.each(function(tabIndex, tab){
    var newId = '#group-0' + groupIndex + '_' + $(tab).attr('href').slice(1);
    $(tab).attr('href', newId  );
  });
});

$contents.each(function(contentIndex, content){
  var groupIndex = contentIndex + 1;
  var $panes = $(content).find('.tab-pane');

  $panes.each(function(paneIndex, pane){
    var newId = 'group-0' + groupIndex + '_' + $(pane).attr('id');
    $(pane).attr('id', newId);
  });
});
```

Comment: Here I changed `$contents.each(function(tabIndex, content)` to I changed `tabIndex` to `contentIndex` i.e. `$contents.each(function(contentIndex, content)` as I was getting error but this is producing different result. `#group-02_01` for tab and `id="group-03_01" for tab-content. So, the content has increased by 1.